# "No such file or directory" error when trying to mount a FSx (Windows File System) share to a EC2 linux instance. How do I resolve this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Before I describe the steps I have taken, I wanted to state that I'm following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/using-file-shares.html#map-shares-linux. Specifically, the "To Mount a File Share on an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance Not Joined to Your Active Directory" section.

1. Created a VPC (let's call it `my-vpc`) with two subnets.
2. Created an AWS Managed Microsoft AD directory, and associated `my-vpc` and the two subnets.

   - The directory DNS name is "corp.example.com".
   - Clicked "Reset user password" in the dashboard for this directory after it was created, and reset the password for the user "Admin" to something else. Pointing this out because I now have the creds for the "Admin" user which will be used later.
3. Created a FSx file system. Choose `my-vpc`, default security group (which allows everything as far as I can tell), and associated the directory from step #2.
4. Created an EC2 RedHat instance. Choose `my-vpc` again for this as well.

So I created all the resources needed and associated all of them to `my-vpc`. Now, I ssh into my EC2 instance and follow the guide above.

5. Created creds.txt as mentioned in the guide. This is what it's in the file (hopefully this is correct):

```
username=Admin
password=[removed]
domain=corp.example.com
```

6. Ran this mount command: `sudo mount -v -t cifs //[ip-of-fsx]/share /mnt/fsx --verbose -o vers=3.0,sec=ntlmsspi,cred=/home/ec2-user/creds.txt,rsize=130048,wsize=130048,cache=none` as mentioned in the guide.

   - The IP is the "Preferred File Server IP Address" as stated in the details of the FSx instance I created.
   - I put in "share" as the file share name since the guide mentions this: "Your file system comes with a default Windows file share, named share."

As stated in the title, when I run this command, I get the following error:
`mount error(2): No such file or directory`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm thinking the FSx isn't reached from the EC2 instance? But they are in the same VPC and the security group of the FSx instance seemingly allows everything?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was actually because of the security group of the FSx instance. I had misread the permissions and thought it allowed everything when it actually didn't. I just had to modify the permissions accordingly, and everything works fine now.